# Generate report slideshow from .Net

Tags: .net, pdf, powerpoint, report, xps

I need to create a simple slide with text and pictures.  This will be done from a .Net 4.0 application.  I'm open to various formats.  I could target PDF, XPS, or PowerPoint for example.  My highest priority is that I can get up and running quickly.  What API's can you recommend?

Note, I am entirely unconcerned with document or vendor preferences.  All users will have PowerPoint, Adobe Reader, or an XPS viewer available.  If the MS Office API's are easy, I will just use those...same goes for any other format.  I'm just having difficulty getting solid answers with my searches.  I'm seeing references to VSTO, Office Interop, and XPS document API's.  None have looked particularly pleasant to use with my basic searches.  I'd also be interested in good PDF or Open Office XML (MS' new format for Office) libraries for example.

Comment: There's code at http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/2/10068596/create-ppt-slides-through-cnet.aspx using COM interop. Might not be very good for server side though as it requires Powerpoint to be installed.

Comment: Thanks.  I am also looking at the open source PDFSharp library.  That way Powerpoint wouldn't have to be installed on the machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to go with OpenXML using Microsoft's Office SDK.  It doesn't use Interop, seems well documented, and it's free.  We'll be producing PowerPoint files, which is preferred by our users.  On nice thing about the Office SDK is MS office does not have to be installed on the machine where the report will be generated.  One less dependency for our application...